# What is this pattern called?

Tags: design-patterns

```
string s = new string("Hello World").Replace(" ","_").ToLower().ToUpper();
```

So you basically return from each method the modified object so can you call new methods on it.

Answer (score 27):

Method chaining. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining))

Answer (score 18):

Or [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Comment: You might say that the objects have a Fluent Interface but the pattern quoted is using chaining?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is provided by Boldewyn, I am just writing this as a suggestion.

When chaining methods like this, try to write it as follows -

```
string s = new string("Hello World")
               .Replace(" ","_")
               .ToLower()
               .ToUpper();
```

This improves code readability.

Comment: Application wise, is this not the way UI Automation code is written ?

Answer (score 0):

Equivenlant to:

```
string s = new string("Hello World");
s = s.Replace(" ","_");
s = s.ToLower();
s = s.ToUpper();
```

Comment: That won't compile without some more semicolons.